# Make an erc20 transfer with web3py

Tags: erc-20, web3.py, python, transfer

how to send an erc20 in web3py please, I have that :

`tx_hash = contract.functions.transfer(destination_address, value).transact({'from': myaddress })`

and I get this error :

ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available'}

I guess am missing signing that or something like that, how can I make a successful  erc20 transfer.

Comment: A couple clarification questions: what node are you connecting to? (I'm guessing Infura.) Also, where are your private keys stored?

Comment: Yes I am using Infura, and the private key is at the same file.

Comment: You should be able to find the appropriate documentation to answer your question here: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-transaction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`transact()` asks the node to sign your transaction using `eth_sendTransaction`. Infura can't do that, because they don't have your keys.

Instead, you can [use the contract object to create an unsigned transaction](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.account.html#sign-a-contract-transaction) like:

```py
contract_call = contract.functions.transfer(destination_address, value)
unsigned_txn = contract_call.buildTransaction({'chainId': 1, 'gasPrice': w3.toWei(100, 'gwei')})
```

Then you can sign the transaction with your private key, and broadcast it:

```
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(unsigned_txn, private_key=private_key)
w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that does an ERC-20 transfer in modern web3.py:

```py
"""Manual transfer script.

- For a hardcoded token, asks to address and amount where to transfer tokens.

- Waits for the transaction to complete
"""
import datetime
import os
import sys
from decimal import Decimal

from eth_account import Account
from eth_account.signers.local import LocalAccount
from web3 import HTTPProvider, Web3
from web3.middleware import construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware

from eth_defi.abi import get_deployed_contract
from eth_defi.token import fetch_erc20_details
from eth_defi.txmonitor import wait_transactions_to_complete

# What is the token we are transferring.
# Replace with your own token address.
ERC_20_TOKEN_ADDRESS = "0x0aC7B3733cBeE5D87A80fbf331f4A0bD01f17386"

# Connect to JSON-RPC node
json_rpc_url = os.environ["JSON_RPC_URL"]
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(json_rpc_url))
print(f"Connected to blockchain, chain id is {web3.eth.chain_id}. the latest block is {web3.eth.block_number:,}")

# Read and setup a local private key
private_key = os.environ.get("PRIVATE_KEY")
assert private_key is not None, "You must set PRIVATE_KEY environment variable"
assert private_key.startswith("0x"), "Private key must start with 0x hex prefix"
account: LocalAccount = Account.from_key(private_key)
web3.middleware_onion.add(construct_sign_and_send_raw_middleware(account))

# Show users the current status of token and his address
erc_20 = get_deployed_contract(web3, "ERC20MockDecimals.json", ERC_20_TOKEN_ADDRESS)
token_details = fetch_erc20_details(web3, ERC_20_TOKEN_ADDRESS)

print(f"Token details are {token_details}")

balance = erc_20.functions.balanceOf(account.address).call()
eth_balance = web3.eth.getBalance(account.address)

print(f"Your balance is: {token_details.convert_to_decimals(balance)} {token_details.symbol}")
print(f"Your have : {eth_balance/(10**18)} ETH for gas fees")

# Ask for transfer details
decimal_amount = input("How many tokens to transfer? ")
to_address = input("Give destination Ethereum address? ")

# Some input validation
try:
    decimal_amount = Decimal(decimal_amount)
except ValueError as e:
    raise AssertionError(f"Not a good decimal amount: {decimal_amount}") from e

assert web3.isChecksumAddress(to_address), f"Not a valid address: {to_address}"

# Fat-fingering check
print(f"Confirm transfering {decimal_amount} {token_details.symbol} to {to_address}")
confirm = input("Ok [y/n]?")
if not confirm.lower().startswith("y"):
    print("Aborted")
    sys.exit(1)

# Convert a human-readable number to fixed decimal with 18 decimal places
raw_amount = token_details.convert_to_raw(decimal_amount)
tx_hash = erc_20.functions.transfer(to_address, raw_amount).transact({"from": account.address})

# This will raise an exception if we do not confirm within the timeout
print(f"Broadcasted transaction {tx_hash.hex()}, now waiting 5 minutes for mining")
wait_transactions_to_complete(web3, [tx_hash], max_timeout=datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))

print("All ok!")
```

[For further information read the full ERC-20 transfer tutorial](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/transfer.html).

Comment: Seems like your link is broken